# OpenGL - How do I fill a buffer with no data?

Tags: opengl, buffer

How do I supply a buffer with a size but no data in OpenGL? I've tried using

```
glBufferData(target, 0, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

but for now I get access violations on drawcall, might be something else.

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I supply a buffer **with a size but no data** in OpenGL?

You've to pass a certain size (in bytes) to the `size` parameter, but pass `nullptr` to `data`. See [`glBufferData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferData.xhtml):

```cpp
GLsizeiptr size_in_bytes = ...;
glBufferData(target, size_in_bytes, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```